# Click on a button that has no Id, class or value

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, dom

this is the HTML code:

```
<table>
<tr><td>Date:</td><td><input type='text' name='d' value=''><br>
(Example:Oct. 8)</td></tr>
<tr><td>Teams:</td><td><input type='text' name='away' value=''> 
at <input type='text' name='home' value=''><br>(Example: Florida at Buffalo
</td></tr>
<tr><td>Time:</td><td><input type='text' name='t' value=''><br>
(Example: 7:00 PM)</td></tr></table><br>
<input type='submit' value='Submit'>
```

this code gives the error run-time error 438:

```
objie.document.getelementsbyvalue("Submit").Click
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no such method on the DOM as `getElementsByValue`. You have [`getElementByID`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/getElementsByTagName), and [`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName).

In your case, you might want to consider [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```
objie.document.querySelector("input[type='submit']")(0).Click
```

assuming there is only one `submit` input on the page.

If there is more than one such input on the page, you'll have to traverse the DOM tree to find this particular `submit`.